# How to unify face and vertex normals

Tags: normals

I created a model in another program, and imported it to Blender to map the UVs. Parts of the model are symmetrically flipped mesh planes. I noticed in Blender that the mirrored objects display as darker, and on further checking, I find that the face and vertex normals are in one direction and the "vertex-per-face" normals are opposite.

I've tried the Recalculate Outside and Flip Normals commands, but that just inverts them without unifying the direction. How can I flip JUST the "vertex-per-face" to get them all in the same direction, as they are in the original un-mirrored object that was copied?

[image: Weird Normals]

Comment: Most likely that's because of custom split normals imported with the object from the 3rd party software; most likely you'll need to remove it in the Object Data tab > Geometry Data rollout. You'll reconstruct shading in Blender if you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Those purple lines are normals generated by *Auto Smooth*. It has checkbox under the Object Data tab > *Normals* rollout. I would recomend you just turn that feature off. If you want some complex shading, you should generaly use *Sharp Edges* with an *Edge Split Modifier*.

[image]

Comment: There always will be normal vectors generated when adjusting edge split because of splitting, no matter which way to use - Autosmooth or Edge Split. As of several recent Blender versions Autosmooth has support of sharp edges, so it's essentially the same as modifier (the only difference is normals exporting)