# Imported object being lit from wrong direction

Tags: objects

I've got a problem where some imported objects are lit from the wrong direction. 
See center object below. 
Normals are ok.
I assume there's some sort of transform linked to the object, but I can't see how or where to reset it.

Any tips much appreciated.[image]

Comment: Try https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76513/strange-black-shading-cannot-fully-light-mesh-cycles

Answer (score 1):

Fixed: Face and vertex normals were okay. 
However, Blender tries to auto generate vertex-per-face normals and get all mixed up. 
Once you turn this off, all works just fine. 
Thanks to this post for the solution: [How to unify face and vertex normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/78099/how-to-unify-face-and-vertex-normals) 
[image]